# Using javascript libraries in Adobe Brackets IDE?

Tags: javascript, libraries, adobe-brackets

How do you use libraries in Brackets without the javascript lint giving errors? For example I am using chart.js and the product works completely fine but Brackets gives an error that Chart was used before being defined. Is there any way to hide this error? I find it helpful for other things but having it always pop up because of one error is annoying. This could be an error on my part as well, maybe I must define the variable even though it is part of the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply jslint options at the top of the js file, for example:

```
/*global window, jQuery, require, charts */
```

There might also be a way to do this globally, i just haven't researched it yet (don't really see a need for it)

Comment: If you don't want to include that header in every single file, you can set a project-wide preference to make a certain list the default across your whole project: create a `.brackets.json` [project settings file](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences), and set the `"jslint.options"` key to an object containing [JSLint settings](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options). For the example above, you'd use `{ "predef": ["window", "jQuery", "require", "charts"] }`