# Using a linter for writing JavaScript involving Backbone on Adobe Brackets

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, adobe-brackets

I'm using Adobe Brackets to do my coding in JavaScript, which can involve jQuery, or in this case, Backbone. I'm simply wondering if there is a linter that can check my JavaScript code and recognize classes such as Backbone that are "imported" from other JavaScript files like backbone-min.js.

[I do have this StackOverflow question to consider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545259/using-javascript-libraries-in-adobe-brackets-ide), but perhaps there has been updates.

Is there one I can install on Adobe Brackets? (A linter, for those of you who are not familiar with a term, is a separate program that automatically flags compiler errors and warnings as you code, much like when you are programming Java on Eclipse / NetBeans, or Android on Android Studio.)

Answer (score 0):

Most linters such as [jshint](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#globals) or [eslint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) support defining global variables.

Try https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-eslint or https://github.com/cfjedimaster/brackets-jshint